# Remove abstract from titlepage

Tags: macros, titles, templates, abstract

Im using a template for my thesis, where I want to delete the "abstract" part from the titlepage. I have to delete something from both the titlepage.tex and macros.tex file, but I get errors every time. And as you can see, I want to avoid the linebreak in the project title

```
\pdfbookmark[0]{English title page}{label:titlepage_en}
\aautitlepage{%
  \englishprojectinfo{
    Project Title Project Title  Project Title Project Title %title
  }{%
    Scientific Theme %theme
  }{%
    Fall Semester 2010 %project period
  }{%
    XXX % project group
  }{%
    %list of group members
    Author 1\\ 
    Author 2\\
    Author 3
  }{%
    %list of supervisors
    Supervisor 1\\
    Supervisor 2
  }{%
    1 % number of printed copies
  }{%
    \today % date of completion
  }%
}{%department and address
  \textbf{Electronics and IT}\\
  Aalborg University\\
  \href{http://www.aau.dk}{http://www.aau.dk}
}{% the abstract
  Here is the abstract
}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\aautitlepage}[3]{%
  {
    %set up various length
    \ifx\titlepageleftcolumnwidth\undefined
      \newlength{\titlepageleftcolumnwidth}
      \newlength{\titlepagerightcolumnwidth}
    \fi
    \setlength{\titlepageleftcolumnwidth}{0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}
    \setlength{\titlepagerightcolumnwidth}{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\titlepageleftcolumnwidth}
    %create title page
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \noindent%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
      \parbox{\titlepageleftcolumnwidth}{
        \iflanguage{danish}{%
          \includegraphics[width=\titlepageleftcolumnwidth]{figures/aau_logo_da}
        }{%
          \includegraphics[width=\titlepageleftcolumnwidth]{figures/aau_logo_en}
        }
      } &
      \parbox{\titlepagerightcolumnwidth}{\raggedleft\sf\small
        #2
      }\bigskip\\
       #1 &
      \parbox[t]{\titlepagerightcolumnwidth}{%
      \textbf{Abstract:}\bigskip\par
        \fbox{\parbox{\titlepagerightcolumnwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
          #3
        }}
      }\\
    \end{tabular}
    \vfill
    \iflanguage{danish}{%
      \noindent{\footnotesize\emph{Rapportens indhold er frit tilgængeligt, men offentliggørelse (med kildeangivelse) må kun ske efter aftale med forfatterne.}}
    }{%
      \noindent{\footnotesize\emph{The content of this report is freely available, but publication (with reference) may only be pursued due to agreement with the author.}}
    }
    \clearpage
  }
}

%Create english project info
\newcommand{\englishprojectinfo}[8]{%
  \parbox[t]{\titlepageleftcolumnwidth}{
    \textbf{Title:}\\ #1\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Theme:}\\ #2\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Project Period:}\\ #3\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Project Group:}\\ #4\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Participant(s):}\\ #5\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Supervisor(s):}\\ #6\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Copies:} #7\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Page Numbers:} \pageref{LastPage}\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Date of Completion:}\\ #8
  }
}

%Create danish project info
\newcommand{\danishprojectinfo}[8]{%
  \parbox[t]{\titlepageleftcolumnwidth}{
    \textbf{Titel:}\\ #1\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Tema:}\\ #2\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Projektperiode:}\\ #3\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Projektgruppe:}\\ #4\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Deltager(e):}\\ #5\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Vejleder(e):}\\ #6\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Oplagstal:} #7\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Sidetal:} \pageref{LastPage}\bigskip\par
    \textbf{Afleveringsdato:}\\ #8
  }
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% An example environment
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{{\color{gray!50}\vrule width 5pt \hspace{5pt}}}
\newshadedtheorem{exa}{Example}[chapter]
\newenvironment{example}[1]{%
        \begin{exa}[#1]
}{%
        \end{exa}
}
```

[image: see image]

Comment: Welcome! Where can the template be obtained? Without it it's very difficult to help.

Comment: Thank you! The template can be obtained from; https://github.com/jkjaer/aauLatexTemplates

Comment: With all the effort of creating a Student Report \titlepage, one would think they would have done a Thesis \titlepage as well.